# Upload file Directly to FTP Server in Python

Tags: python, api, ftp

Is there any way to directly send files from one API to another FTP server without downloading them to local in Python 3.

Currently we downloading from one API to local and then sending it to FTP server, want to avoid that hop from data flow by directly sending files to server.

Comment: *"avoid that hop"* is vague. Do you want to avoid (temporarily) storing the file to local file system? Or do you want to save the bandwidth?

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl , I want to avoid downloading files to local, what we need is to directly send file from API to FTP. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use byte data of the file(it will store as in-memory) and pass that to another API.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options would be having another API function (TransferFile, ...), which will transfer data from API server to FTP site. Then you just call that API method from your code without downloading data to the local server.

Answer (score 0):

The FTP protocol has provision for initiating a data transfert between two remote hosts from a third party client. This is called the proxy mode. Unfortunately, most servers disable it for security reasons, because it used to be a very efficient way for DOS attacks.

If you have control on both servers and if both use FTP and if they are not publicly exposed, this can be very efficient.

In any other use case, the data will have to pass through the client. The best that can be done is to open both connections and transfer data to the target host as soon as it has been received from the source without storing it on disk.